# MQTT.FX - how to install on RPI 3 from MQtt.fx website

Tags: software-installation

I’m new to RPI and MQTT.fx.

I have mosquito installed on my RPI and tested Ok, per the instructions on http://www.switchdoc.com/2016/02/tutorial-installing-and-testing-mosquitto-mqtt-on-raspberry-pi/ 
(Ok, no problems )

I have the GUI MQtt.fx  (version 1.5.0) working on my windows 7 laptop
(OK, no problems)

Now ...
I want to get MQtt.fx installed and working on my Raspberry pi 3, but when I download any one of the .deb files from  http://www.jensd.de/apps/mqttfx/1.5.0/, and then try to install it with

Sudo gdebi filename.deb,

my RPI just comes back saying … uninstallable .. wrong architecture.

Now, ... I have tried several of the files located on the above web site, including the 2 that end in .deb . All cause the above error message.

Note:-
When I query my RPI OS by using ‘uname -a’ command, it comes back with  …Linux raspberrypi 4.9.35-v7 #1014 …..armv71 …

How can I correctly install MTQQ.fx on my RPI version 3 board ?

There are several existing questions about MQTT or mosquitto on this site, but there is little clear information about which MQTT.fx file to use and how to install it correctly on an RPI 3 board.

How can the above problem ...wrong architecture ... be resolved ? which .deb file will work ? how can it be correctly installed ?

Comment: You dont need to install the mqtt.fx on your raspberry pi. MQTT.fx is just a client, so you can run it on your windows machine and connect with the raspberry pi, where the mosquito server is running on. After successful connection you can see every data transfers on the selected topics

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment. But in a situation where the laptop is located away from the raspberry Pi it is useful to have MQTT.fx running on the RPI. The answer below provides a solution - use the older version 1.0.0 that can be downloaded and installed on an RPI. Again, many thanks for your helpful advice,

Comment: I have just pushed the lastest version of MQTT.fx as JAR package for you. Here is the link:
http://www.jensd.de/apps/mqttfx/1.6.0-gciot-demos/mqttfx-1.6.0-gciot-demo1.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the packages offered are listed as '32bit' and '64bit'. You can safely assume that means x86, **not ARM**. Since your Pi has an ARM processor, it can't 'understand' programs compiled for x86 processors, so attempting to install that .deb package simply won't work.

MQTT.FX is appparently licensed under the Apache License, but no source code seems to be available. There is, however, a JAR file from version 1.0.0 which you can use, available [here](http://www.jensd.de/apps/mqttfx/1.0.0/MQTT.fx-1.0.0-EXEC-JAR.zip) (note: direct download link).

Simply download and extract the ZIP file linked, then install the JRE:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

Then execute MQTT.FX:

```
java -jar MQTT.fx-jfx.jar
```

(run that in the directory `app` from the ZIP you extracted). If this is unsuccessful, it is likely that it relies on platform specific features, in which case you will need to look for another MQTT client; [HiveMQ list a few](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/seven-best-mqtt-client-tools) on their site. As pointed out in the comments, though, be sure to consider whether you actually need a client on your Pi... If the Pi is accessible to the internet or your local network, it may be easier to connect from a different device with better support.