# which version mqttfx for installation on RPI 4

Tags: mqtt

I want to install mqttfx on my RPI 4 (Buster) What is the right version and where can I download? Which java is necessary?

Comment: perhaps [this duplicate question and answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/78262/mqtt-fx-how-to-install-on-rpi-3-from-mqtt-fx-website) will help?

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. 2 days ago I read this instruction and installed the software as discribed but I got several java errors and no succes

Comment: `I got several java errors` - perhaps if you shared some of the problems you have then

Comment: e. g. linked mqttfx jar is not compatible for arm. I will install again java, mqttfx and come back. I saw a link for Raspberry mqttfx.